# Python lists, join 2 zipped lists

Tags: python, list

```
[('BMW 3 SERIES ESTATE', 'Premium', 'GBP 1055.75', 'Automatic Transmission', '5', '5'), ('FIAT 500', 'Mini', '75.48', 'Manual Transmission', 'n/a', '3'), ('VAUXHALL CORSA', 'Economy', ' 79.48', 'Manual Transmission', '5', '5')]
[('14.00', '14.99', '39.00'), ('14.00', '14.99', '39.00'), ('14.00', '14.99', '39.00')]
```

I have these two zipped lists that I would like to join like this:

```
('BMW 3 SERIES ESTATE', 'Premium', 'GBP 1055.75', 'Automatic Transmission', '5', '5', '14.00', '14.99', '39.00')
```

How can I achieve this ? thx

Comment: What have you already tried, and where are you stuck? Why does the output only contain part of the data? Please read [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask). You can [edit] to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [('BMW 3 SERIES ESTATE', 'Premium', 'GBP 1055.75', 'Automatic Transmission', '5', '5'), ('FIAT 500', 'Mini', '75.48', 'Manual Transmission', 'n/a', '3'), ('VAUXHALL CORSA', 'Economy', ' 79.48', 'Manual Transmission', '5', '5')]
b = [('14.00', '14.99', '39.00'), ('14.00', '14.99', '39.00'), ('14.00', '14.99', '39.00')]
[x+y for (x,y) in zip(a,b)]
```

Output

```
[('BMW 3 SERIES ESTATE',
  'Premium',
  'GBP 1055.75',
  'Automatic Transmission',
  '5',
  '5',
  '14.00',
  '14.99',
  '39.00'),
 ('FIAT 500',
  'Mini',
  '75.48',
  'Manual Transmission',
  'n/a',
  '3',
  '14.00',
  '14.99',
  '39.00'),
 ('VAUXHALL CORSA',
  'Economy',
  ' 79.48',
  'Manual Transmission',
  '5',
  '5',
  '14.00',
  '14.99',
  '39.00')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls1 = [('BMW 3 SERIES ESTATE', 'Premium', 'GBP 1055.75', 'Automatic Transmission', '5', '5'), ('FIAT 500', 'Mini', '75.48', 'Manual Transmission', 'n/a', '3'), ('VAUXHALL CORSA', 'Economy', ' 79.48', 'Manual Transmission', '5', '5')]
ls2 = [('14.00', '14.99', '39.00'), ('14.00', '14.99', '39.00'), ('14.00', '14.99', '39.00')]

ans = ls1[0]+ls2[0]
print(ans)
```

output:

```
['BMW 3 SERIES ESTATE', 'Premium', 'GBP 1055.75', 'Automatic Transmission', '5', '5', '14.00', '14.99', '39.00']
```

is this what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to be able to add them all together, not just the first element:

```
data = [('BMW 3 SERIES ESTATE', 'Premium', 'GBP 1055.75', 'Automatic Transmission', '5', '5'), ('FIAT 500', 'Mini', '75.48', 'Manual Transmission', 'n/a', '3'), ('VAUXHALL CORSA', 'Economy', ' 79.48', 'Manual Transmission', '5', '5')]
nums = [('14.00', '14.99', '39.00'), ('14.00', '14.99', '39.00'), ('14.00', '14.99', '39.00')]

for i in range(len(data)):
    data[i] = list(data[i])
    for j in range(len(nums[i])):
        data[i].append(nums[i][j])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_a = [('BMW 3 SERIES ESTATE', 'Premium', 'GBP 1055.75', 'Automatic Transmission', '5', '5'), ('FIAT 500', 'Mini', '75.48', 'Manual Transmission', 'n/a', '3'), ('VAUXHALL CORSA', 'Economy', ' 79.48', 'Manual Transmission', '5', '5')]
list_b = [('14.00', '14.99', '39.00'), ('14.00', '14.99', '39.00'), ('14.00', '14.99', '39.00')]

final_list = []

for element in list_a:
    temp_list = []
    k = 0
    
    # First append each elements into a temporary list
    for i in range(len(element)):
        temp_list.append(element[i])
        
    # Now append the items of list_b into temp_list
    for j in range(len(list_b)):
        temp_list.append(list_b[k][j])
    
    final_list.append(tuple(temp_list))  # Appending to the final list after transforming into a tuple
    
    k = k+1                       # Incrementing in order to match the len of list_b
    del temp_list                 # deleting the temp_list to avoid similar elements
```